# How would one get an attachment from a message, then grab it and send it from a bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, attachment

Here is the code I have tried.

```
embed.setImage(message.attachments.url)
```

Plus

```
embed.setImage(message.attachments[0])
```

But when I include an attachment in my message, it only shows the text within the message I sent, not the attachment

*note** `embed` is the MessageEmbed constructor.

Comment: Tip for future posts, please put the Question into the Question, not the Title.

Answer (score 1):

[`Message#attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). You'll have to get the first element in the collection (if there is any) and then set the image.

*Note that URLs do not count as attachments.*

---

```js
if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
    embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url)
}
```